# Ruby GC::Profiler no output

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm running a ruby script and trying to see the GC stats on it, but the output is just empty string. Here are the contents of my script:

```
class NumberPool

  ...

  attr_accessor :sets

  def initialize
    @sets = []
  end

  def allocate
    allocated_number = Random.rand(min_bound..max_bound)
    sets.each do |set|
      next unless set.range.include?(allocated_number)
      return set.range.delete(allocated_number)
    end
    factor = allocated_number / batch_size
    min = factor * batch_size
    max = min + batch_size
    sub = SubPool.new(min, max)
    sub.range.delete(allocated_number)
    sets.push(sub)
    allocated_number
  end

  ...

def run_test
  GC::Profiler.enable

  a = NumberPool.new
  p a.allocate

  GC::Profiler.report
end

puts run_test
```

When I run this, the output is:

```
$ ruby number_pool.rb
1855532
```

I expected to see something from the GC report in standard out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, but maybe GC hasn't triggered (no need to collect garbage yet because plenty of free memory).

See what happens if you force GC by adding GC.start (modify code like so):

```
   p a.allocate
   GC.start
   GC::Profiler.report
```